# How to run/create/launch a container from an image in VS Code?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-container, docker-image, docker-run

Is there a way to run/create/launch a container from an image in VS Code (e.g., one I downloaded from Docker Hub), or do I need to do it from outside VS Code (e.g., `docker run` from the command-line, or the Docker app, ...)?

I have the [Docker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker) and [Docker Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.docker-explorer) extensions installed, but I don't see any `docker run` functionality in them (e.g., in the Command Palette, the sidebar, or right-clicking on an image).

Comment: Playing with the VSCode Docker extension, there's a very limited ability to launch a container – if you already have the image locally, you can right-click, "Run" it – but there are almost no options available for persistent storage, port mapping, or any other configuration.  Right-clicking on a `docker-compose.yml` file gives a couple more options.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze.  Hmm, I don't even see the "right-click > "Run" it.